# Unable to pass Ioptions to Static extensions method or warmup singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create cosmos Db database and collection on startup.cs of my microService. I have tried 2 approaches. One is to create a static extension method for service and do the initialization for cosmos db there. The other approach is to just create a singleton(ICosmosDbInitializer) and do the initialization in the constructor by using getAawaiter().Getresult() since database and collection creation methods are async.

I have also created an Ioption to save cosmos db configuration like databaseName, DbUrl, Accesskey etc.

```
 services.Configure<CosmosDbOptions>((cosmosDbOptions) =>
            {
// more code here
            });
```

My issue is that I am unable to inject this Option to either static extension method or singelton.

**1. Using Static extension method**

**Inside Startup.cs**

//Not sure how to pass cosmosDbOptions here

```
 services.ConfigureCosmosDbClient(???);
```

Inside static extension class

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureCosmosDbClient(this IServiceCollection services, CosmosDbOptions cosmosDbOptions)
        {
        }
```

**2. Using Warmed up singelton.**
 Need to create warmup singleton so that database and collection is created before first user request. Here it fails at runtime when trying to inject Iptions.

**Inside startup.cs**

```
 services.AddSingleton<CosmosDbInitializer, CosmosDbInitializer>();

       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
            {
    app.ApplicationServices.GetService<CosmosDbInitializer>();
            }
```

**Inside singleton**

```
public CosmosDbInitializer(CosmosDbOptions cosmosDbOptions) :
        {
}
```

**EDIT: Added error (from comments)**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'CosmosDbOptions' while attempting to activate 'CosmosDbInitializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You registered your options as `TOptions` not like `Service`. It tell you your log error message.

Try change

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureCosmosDbClient(this IServiceCollection services, CosmosDbOptions cosmosDbOptions)
        {
        }
```

to

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureCosmosDbClient(this IServiceCollection services, IOptionsMonitor<CosmosDbOptions> cosmosDbOptions)
```

> IOptionsMonitor is used to retrieve options and manage
>   options notifications for TOptions instances.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2)